# ! LaTeX Error: File `res.cls' not found. Why?

Tags: errors

I am new to Latex and would like to create a resume. I found a resume template on this [link](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/) and downloaded res9a.tex on my computer. When I open this file on Texmaker and click on Quick Build, I get the following error:**! LaTeX Error: File `res.cls' not found.**

So I went back to the link and clicked on res.cls, which opened the following [webpage](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls). What should I do after this in order to successfully run the resume code on Texmaker?

For convenience sake, the resume code given in res9a.tex is as follows:

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[margin]{res}
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download      helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % set width of text portion

 \begin{document}

 % Center the name over the entire width of resume:
 \moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf Susan R. Bumpershoot}
 % Draw a horizontal line the whole width of resume:
  \moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip
 % address begins here
 % Again, the address lines must be centered over entire width of resume:
  \moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{1985 Storm Lane}
  \moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{Troy, NY 12180}
  \moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{(518) 273-0014 or (518) 272-6666}


 \begin{resume}

 \section{OBJECTIVE}  A position in the field of computers with special 
            interests in business applications programming, 
            information processing, and management systems. 


 \section{EDUCATION} {\sl Bachelor of Science,} Interdisciplinary Science \\
                  % \sl will be bold italic in New Century Schoolbook (or
              % any postscript font) and just slanted in
          % Computer Modern (default) font
            Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY, 
            expected December 1990 \\
            Concentration: Computer Science \\
            Minor: Management 


\section{COMPUTER \\ SKILLS} {\sl Languages \& Software:} COBOL, IFPS, Focus, 
     Megacalc, Pascal, Modula2, C, APL, SNOBOL, 
            FORTRAN, LISP, SPIRES, BASIC, VSPC Autotab, 
            IBM 370 Assembler, Lotus 1-2-3. \\
            {\sl Operating Systems:} MTS, TSO, Unix. 

 \section{EXPERIENCE} {\sl Business Applications Programmer} \hfill Fall 1990 \\
            Allied-Signal Bendix Friction Materials Division, 
            Financial Planning Department, Latham, NY 
             \begin{itemize}  \itemsep -2pt %reduce space between items
             \item Developed four ``user friendly" forecasting 
                systems each of which produces 18 to 139 
                individual reports. 
            \item   Developed or improved almost all IFPS 
                programs used for financial reports. 
            \end{itemize}

            {\sl Research Programmer} \hfill            Summer 1990 \\
            Psychology Department, Rensselaer Polytechnic 
            Institute 
             \begin{itemize}  \itemsep -2pt %reduce space between items
             \item Performed computer aided statistical analysis 
                of data. 
             \end{itemize} 
            {\sl Assistant Manager} \hfill        Summers 1988-89 \\
            Thunder Restaurant, Canton, CT
              \begin{itemize}
               \item Recognized need for, developed, and wrote 
                employee training manual. Performed various 
                duties including cooking, employee training, 
                ordering, and inventory control. 
               \end{itemize} 

  \section{COMMUNITY \\ SERVICE}  Organized and directed the 1988 and 1989 Grand 
             Marshall Week \newline ``Basketball Marathon.'' A 24 hour 
            charity event to benefit the Troy Boys Club. Over 
            250 people participated each year. 

  \section{EXTRA-CURRICULAR \\ ACTIVITIES}             
        Elected {\it House Manager}, Rho Phi Sorority \\
        Elected {\it Sports Chairman} \\
        Attended Krannet Leadership Conference \\
            Headed delegation to Rho Phi Congress \\
            Junior varsity basketball team \\
            Participant, seven intramural athletic teams 


 \end{resume}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, the `res` class does not belong to standard distributions. It is not even in CTAN.

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question, as it is still unclear, what TeX-system you are using and where you stored the downloaded class file.  If you stored it in the directory, where your LaTeX-file resides, it should be found by all TeX-installations, which are known to me.  On some systems (namely everything on Unix-like computers), you can use `kpsewhich tex rep.cls` to detect, if the class is found.  Sometimes you have to update the database of installed files by running `mktexlsr` or `texhash`.  So please, give us precise infos about your setup.

Comment: Also you said, you downloaded `res3a.cls` but in your document your are using `res` which should be `res.cls`.

Comment: Don't use the class anymore. Please please don't. It is old and should be left to die in peace.

Comment: [This really can't proof what i said](https://twitter.com/templateGundar/status/777413569612812289). Maybe you are interested in a [CV template that lets you design the layout](https://twitter.com/templateGundar/status/820195319954702337)

Comment: You need to download the file called `res.cls`, as you did with the `.tex` file, and place `res.cls` in the same folder as the `.tex` file. (Unless you want to take @Johannes_B's advice, and use something else.)

Comment: It *is* on CTAN, in `latex\contrib\resume` (not `resumecls`) , and dates back to `latex2.09`.

Comment: @Jan I am using Texmaker software on Windows 8. The file res9a.tex was downloaded and stored in the Window's default Download folder.

Comment: @Supermario TeXmaker is only the editor and does not count.  As Torbjørn said: download the correct class, store it in the same directory as your TeX-file and it should work.

Comment: A `*.cls` file is not a template, it is a class file. In general a LaTeX file is either a `class` (with file extension `.cls`) or a `package` (with file extension `.sty`) or code of some sort (with a  file extension `.tex`).

Comment: @Jan How do I go about downloading the res.cls? If you click on the "webpage" mentioned in my answer then you would reach a page which has a lot of lines of code. What should I do after that?

Comment: @Supermario just mark everything, open a new file in your editor, paste everything from the webpage into that file, store it as res.cls besides your main document.

Comment: I wonder why new users want to get stuck quickly in the mud of some bizarre class instead of become more experts with standard classes. I known  the craving of rediscover outstanding  classes that nobody remember, but believe me, often the adventure end in pain.

Comment: If you really, really, really want to use this class: Right-click to the [`res.cls` link](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls) (instead of left-click) and select "Save Target as ..." to save the file as `res.cls` in the same folder as your `*.tex` file. After saving the file, open it so see if you've saved the correct content (and not only the link address or a HTML page or something like this). However: How to download files from web is off-topic here.

Answer (score 7):

Go to this website and to download this file named [res.cls](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/). Put it with the `.tex` file together. Then it will work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). In the question, the OP (original poster) attached a link that is the result of clicking your. Please explain how can the OP (or anybody else) download the `res.sty` from this website.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Follow his link, Open the link to res.sty, copy it into a .txt file, then rename the file "res.sty". Then, place the file into the same directory as the tex file you are trying to run.

Comment: Actually, it's `res.cls`, not `res.sty`.

Comment: Welcome, it is unclear which link you are referring to. Nevertheless, `res.sty` is outdated since 1994. An updated version was published in 2001. But to be honest, nobody should use `res.cls` or `res.sty`.